# Attribute of a constant displays in view on local win instance, doesnt not display/update properly when put onto aws

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

So I have created a constant for refering to a scheduled object that I do at initialisation:

```
rule_engine = Ruleby::Core::Engine.new
Rails.logger.debug "#{Time.now.utc} - Created New Rules Engine"
RULES_ENG = RulesEngineCaller.new(rule_engine)
```

Which is scheduled to run every x minutes through my code, this invokes a rules engine that runs and I keep track of how often it runs, it initialises like this:

```
require_relative 'rules_eng'
require_relative 'notification'

class RulesEngineCaller
  # To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
  attr_accessor :rule_engine, :last_processing_timestamp, :last_processing_duration,     :last_processing_duration_history

  def initialize(rule_engine)
    @last_processing_timestamp = Time.now.utc
    @last_processing_duration = 0
    @last_processing_duration_history = Array.new
  end
```

Which when the actual functions are called will update a few of the values:

```
@last_processing_duration = Time.now.utc - d
```

THAT should then display as part of my home "view" using this:

```
<%= RULES_ENG.last_processing_duration.to_s %>
```

This works absolutely perfectly on my local copy, which is under Windows and MySQL and such... But I put this on a AWS instance I have and the values either dont display at all OR they display for a value they would of been in the past until I refresh it and goes back to not display it at all.

The only differences I can figure is: Redhat, Passenger & Apache to make it work on the AWS where my local copy is just local. And changing it to RULES::last_processing_duration etc doesnt seem to make much difference.

Um, Help this is driving me up the wall as Ive been trying to figure this out on and off  when I get back to it for about 3 weeks now... Rails is not exactly something I have a large amount of experience in.

Comment: I havent solved this completely but I reduced the amount of work my rules engine was doing in memory and it started to work by magic! Then it went back up a few hours later and stopped working.

Pretty sure its going to boil down to point releases and memory management by rails/ruby. Just for anyone who looks this up and has my level of frustration (and sees there is no answer).